# Which data is returned by useSWR in case it's still loading/validating?

Tags: javascript, ajax, next.js, use-swr

I have the following call of `useSWR`:

```
const { data: idpData } = useSWR<Foo[]>(
    buildUrl((): string => `/[...]/idps`),
    (url: string): Promise<Foo[]> =>
        fetch(url, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } })
            .then((res): Promise<PaginationWithContentDetails> => res.json())
            .then((data): Foo[] => data.content),
);
```

The following is how the resulting data is used somewhere:

```
{idpData?.map(
    (idp: Foo): ReactElement => (
        <option key={idp.id} value={idp.id} disabled={!hasEmailValid}>
            {idp.name}
        </option>
    ),
)}
```

During tests I recognized that most of the times the array behind `data.content` is returned, but sometimes the JSON object itself of the response is returned. In the latter case the above rendering fails, because I do have some data, but it's an object instead of an array, so the `map` call isn't available.

> idpData?.map is not a function

This is unexpected to me, my understanding of `useSWR` is that it either returns `undefined`/`null` as data or, depending on the actual config, some given fallback data or formerly available data from earlier responses. I don't give any fallback data and even data of former results should always be arrays only from my understanding.

- https://swr.vercel.app/docs/advanced/understanding
- https://swr.vercel.app/docs/advanced/performance#dependency-collection

To me it looks like that sometimes the intermediate result of the first `.then` is returned. But there is further processing coded and it would violate the signature to return arbitrary intermediate data. OTOH, if I get unexpected intermediate data, it's really only the JSON response body, never the response itself or some other unexpected stuff. So the first `.then` seems to succeed always. Consequently, if I change my fetching code to always return the JSON only and handle the array access during the render code, things succeed:

```
{idpData?.content?.map(
```

**So, which data is guaranteed to be returned by useSWR in case it's still loading or validating or fetching or ...? Can it really be intermediate data in case multiple processings happen on the response within the fetcher callback?**

Thanks!

Comment: "*it looks like that sometimes the intermediate result of the first `.then` is returned*" - no, that should be impossible. The `useSWR` only gets to see the final step promise returned from the callback, nothing else.

Comment: "*there is further processing coded*" - do you mean after the hook call, or do you mean that you haven't shown us the actual code of your `then` callbacks? Are there any `.catch()` callbacks or similar for error handling?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you verified that it really is the full JSON response body that you get? Maybe there's a problem where the response has nested `{"content": {"content": …}}`? Have you logged the promise that is returned?

Comment: `"there is further processing coded"` refers to that there are two instead of one `.then` only. There's nothing more of interest than the above. Debugging was done using browser's dev tools and logging actual data where the array contents are mapped. Looked like the JSON only always, no nested things.

Comment: So the returned values of `useSWR` for me are really only either `Foo[]` or `undefined`/`null`? Maybe there's a problem with requests to the same keys but different fetcher callback then or something. Feel free to clarify the returns of `useSWR` as an answer to accept that.

Comment: I think I found it: There's a call for `useSWR` with the same key like in the example above, but the fetcher of that returned JSON only, not the content array. The problem was triggered by clicking around through the web-UI and that triggered the different calls to `useSWR` and resulted in differently returned data in the end.